How to create a measure in LookML based on different views/explorers
I have created two views from a table with some implemented measures. It's something basic, illustrated as follows:
view : view_A {

dimension: Time_A {....}
dimension: Value_A {...}
dimension: code_B {..}
measure: Total_Value_A {
         type: sum .... sql: {$Value_A}
          }
}

AND 

view : view_B {

dimension: Time_B {....}
dimension: Value_B {...}
dimension: code_B {..}
measure: Total_Value_B {
         type: sum .... sql: {$Value_B}
          }
}

We have two separate explorers based on each view. When we execute the explorers, we get the correct result when using the time dimension for each one of them. Now, it has been requested to implement another metric, which is a combination of the basic ones:
Total_Value_C = Total_Value_A + Total_Value_B

Is it possible to achieve something like this in LookML? What could be the right approach, especially considering that each measure is based on a different time dimension?

Yes, it is possible to reference dimensions/measures in other views if you have an Explore that joins views together.
In either view_A or view_B you could have
measure: total_C {
   sql: ${view_A.Total_Value_A} + ${view_B.Total_Value_B}
}

It doesn't matter as much which view you put measure in, but you have to make sure you have an Explore that references both. For example:
explore: some_explore {
   from: view_A
   join: view_B {
      type: ...
      relationship: ...
      sql_on: ... ;;
   }

Without the Explore with both views referenced, you'll get a LookML error saying the measure from other view doesn't exist.
